# How can I get the list of Open Channels more than 1000 in android using the SendBird SDK?

Tags: android, sendbird

I'm developing the chatting application using the SendBird SDK in android studio.

How can I get the list of Open Channels more than 1000?

Answer (score 1):

You can create use an `OpenChannelListQuery` to traverse through your list of channels in fixed chunks.

```java
OpenChannelListQuery query = OpenChannel.createOpenChannelListQuery();
query.setLimit(30);
query.next(new OpenChannelListQuery.OpenChannelListQueryResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(List<OpenChannel> list, SendBirdException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            // Error!
        }
        // list contains the first 30 channels.
    }
});
```

As long as your `query` instance is the same, you can call `query.next()` until you obtain as many channels as you want.

```java
query.next(new OpenChannelListQuery.OpenChannelListQueryResultHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(List<OpenChannel> list, SendBirdException e) {
        // list contains the next 30 channels.
    }
});
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that the first `query.next()` must be completely finished before you can call `query.next()` again. That is, make sure the first `onResult()` is called before calling `query.next()` again.